# Почему текст становится видимым после переворота экрана Swift 4?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift4

Здравствуйте!

Вопрос такой. Увеличиваю размер textView с помощью данного кода:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
    textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    var newFrame = textView.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
    textView.frame = newFrame   
}
```

Текст вводится без проблем, ячейка увеличивается, НО, текст почему-то невидно и он становится видимым после переворота экрана в любую сторону, это было бы полезно, будь у меня приложение про секретные переписки и я сделал бы это фичей.

С чем это может быть связано? И что происходит при повороте экрана?[[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы используете autolayout?  Скорее всего при повороте экрана меняется размер constraints и textView становится больше. Вам надо сделать priority одной и constraints чуть меньше, чтобы она могла меняться в зависимости от размера textView. Так же можете попробоваться обновить в ручную setNeedsLayout/layoutIfNeeded. Но это не поможет если constraints настроены не верно.

Comment: @VitaliEller почему тогда при повороте экрана в исходное состояние мы видим растянутую ячейку?

Comment: Потому что при первом повороте система уже знает нужный фрейм, она его нарисовала, и при повторном повороте никаких изменений не происходит, фрейм остается таким же. Попробуйте написать много текста, повернуть телефон, увидите этот текст, удалите его, поверните обратно, и попробуйте сново его написать. По идее проблема должна повториться.

Comment: @VitaliEller , возможно, но я изменил метод  textViewDidChange, на другой код и ячейка растягивается так как нужно.

Comment: Тогда добавьте правильный ответ, чтобы другие, кто столкнулся с такой же проблемой, знали как ее решить.

Comment: @VitaliEller да, сейчас добавлю

Comment: setAnimationsEnabled вызывает обновление экрана, поэтому все заработало.

Comment: @VitaliEller да, конечно.

Answer (score 0):

Решение данной проблемы:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let size = textView.bounds.size
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

    if size.height != newSize.height {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        tableView?.beginUpdates()
        tableView?.endUpdates()
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
}
```